# Why the selected numbers in the variables are not the same as in the program it self?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a trackBar in my form1 designer where i can click twice. First time i select a number of a file for example file number 5052 and another click for exmaple on 5473.

Then i assign the selections to two int variables Start and End:
But i see using a breakpoint that Start is: 5051 and End is: 5472
In my new form i did:

```
mtp1Start = myTrackPanelss1.Start;
mtp1End = myTrackPanelss1.End;
```

Now mtp1Start = 5051
And mtp1End = 5472

myTrackPanelss1 is a UserControl of a trackPanel.

The question is where is the problem when i make the selection on the trackPanel why it's showing different selected numbers from what i click on and what i get in the variables ?

This is the trackPanel control code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace mws
{
    public partial class MyTrackPanelss : UserControl
    {
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int End { get; set; }

        private int _tbPadding = 14;
        private float _penWidth = 15F;

        public int TBPadding { get { return _tbPadding; } }
        public float PenWidth { get { return _penWidth; } }

        public MyTrackPanelss()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Start = 0;
            End = this.trackBar1.Maximum;

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlDark))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, this.ClientRectangle);
            using (GraphicsPath gPath = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gPath.AddLine(new Point(_tbPadding, 0), new Point(_tbPadding, panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2));
                gPath.AddLine(new Point(this.trackBar1.ClientSize.Width - _tbPadding, panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2),
                    new Point(this.trackBar1.ClientSize.Width - _tbPadding, 0));

                using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ActiveCaption))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(sb, gPath);

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gPath);
            }

            int maxRange = this.trackBar1.Maximum - this.trackBar1.Minimum;
            //_tbPadding for end and start of ticks of trackbar
            double rangeOne = ((this.panel1.ClientSize.Width - _tbPadding * 2.0) / (double)maxRange);
            if (End < Start)
            {
                int tmp = End;
                End = Start;
                Start = tmp;
            }

            if (End == Start)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot select start point and end point on the same place");
            }
            float xVal = (float)(_tbPadding + (Start * rangeOne));
            float xVal2 = (float)(_tbPadding + (End * rangeOne));

            if (Start >= this.trackBar1.Minimum)
            {
                using (Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, _penWidth))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(greenPen, new PointF(xVal, 1), new PointF(xVal, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2));
                    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black))
                    {
                        p.StartCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF(xVal, 1), new PointF(xVal, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2));
                    }
                    e.Graphics.DrawString((Start+1).ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(xVal, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2F));
                }
            }

            if (End <= this.trackBar1.Maximum)
            {
                using (Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, _penWidth))
                {
                    SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(End.ToString(), this.Font);
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, new PointF(xVal2, 1), new PointF(xVal2, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2));
                    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black))
                    {
                        p.StartCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF(xVal2, 1), new PointF(xVal2, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height - 2));
                    }
                    if (xVal2 - xVal > s.Width + redPen.Width)
                        e.Graphics.DrawString((End+1).ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(xVal2 - s.Width, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2F));
                    else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString((End+1).ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(xVal2, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2F));
                }
            }

            string t = "click left to specify start, right to specify end";
            SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(t, this.Font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(t, this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF((this.panel1.ClientSize.Width - sz.Width) / 2F, 0));
        }

        private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int maxRange = this.trackBar1.Maximum - this.trackBar1.Minimum;
            //_tbPadding for end and start of ticks of trackbar
            double rangeOne = ((this.panel1.ClientSize.Width - _tbPadding * 2.0) / (double)maxRange);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.X >= _tbPadding && e.X <= panel1.ClientSize.Width - _tbPadding)
            {
                int i = (int)((e.X - _tbPadding) / rangeOne);
                Start = i;
                trackBar1.Value = i;

                this.panel1.Invalidate();
            }

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.X >= _tbPadding && e.X <= panel1.ClientSize.Width - _tbPadding + rangeOne)
            {
                int i = (int)((e.X - _tbPadding) / rangeOne);
                End = i;
                trackBar1.Value = i;

                this.panel1.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a screenshot of the trackPanel after i did a selection:

[image: Selections]

You can see the selections i did the Green color and the Red color on the bottom.
I'm doing the selections by clicking with the mouse on the light blue color of the trackPanel.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a zero-indexed collection in there somewhere, so both your start and end values are 1 less than what you expect?

Comment: Tim yes you right they are less 1 then what i excepted. Like in the image i uploaded the variables should contain what in the image: 5052 and 5473 the question is where is the problem i guess it's somewhere in the trackPanel UserControl code.

Comment: @Tim Given that _tbPadding and _penWidth differ by 1, that's always possible. If I've read the question correctly there are two mouse clicks involved, so another possibility is that the mouse is actually moving just enough between them.

Comment: ClickRick true in the trackPanel code there are two mouse clicks. Is there any solution for that ? In the trackPanel code you can see panel1_MouseClick event and there is where the variables Start and End get assigned.

Comment: The problem is that later on another class i'm looping over the selected numbers for (int i = mtpStart; i < mtpEnd; i++) and they are not the same numbers that show in the image in the program when i did the selections. The trackBar panel show 5052 and 5473 but in fact i loop over 5051 and 5472 and i want to loop over what it show in the program when i make the selections like in the image i uploaded above.

Comment: I tried now again the first number in the program when i run it is 1 and last one is 8757 and i checked on my hard disk there are realy 8757 files. But the variables contain the numbers less 1.

Comment: On the lines that say `int i = (int)((e.X - _tbPadding) / rangeOne);` in `panel1_MouseClick`, the `if` conditions allow those lines to execute when `e.X` is as low as `_tbPadding`, but the result then will be that `i` will be set to zero.  You seem not to want that result, so perhaps you should not be subtracting `_tbPadding`.